# Hive doesn't detect current namenode

Tags: hadoop, hive, apache-zeppelin, high-availability

I try requesting Hive database with Hive and Zeppelin but i get this error :

```
SemanticException Unable to fetch table table_name. org.apache.hadoop.ipc.RemoteException(org.apache.hadoop.ipc.StandbyException): Operation category READ is not supported in state standby
```

I get 2 namenode : A and B
When A is active and B in state stanby i can request my table without problems.

```
hdfs haadmin -getServiceState A
active
hdfs haadmin -getServiceState B
standby
```

if i switch both state with :

```
hdfs haadmin -failover A B
```

A is standby and B is now active

```
hdfs haadmin -getServiceState A
standby
hdfs haadmin -getServiceState B
active
```

now my request doesn't work and get the error :

```
SemanticException Unable to fetch table table_name. org.apache.hadoop.ipc.RemoteException(org.apache.hadoop.ipc.StandbyException): Operation category READ is not supported in state standby
```

it seam that my Hive is well configured for HA :

```
hive --config /etc/hive/conf/conf.server --service metatool -listFSRoot
Listing FS Roots..
hdfs://HA-NAME/apps/hive/warehouse
hdfs://HA-NAME/apps/hive/warehouse/table1.db
hdfs://HA-NAME/apps/hive/warehouse/table2.db
...
```

but with command : `show create table1` in Hive , i get :
`LOCATION ' hdfs://A/data/.... '`

The probleme seam come from the namenode B, or Hive alway use namenode A as active namenode even if it is in standby.

i use HA name for connecting my kafka connect to HDFS without problem too.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

problem resolved by migrating my table from A to HA name.

before i get :

```
show create table1 
LOCATION ' hdfs://A/data/.... '
```

i deleted the table, hdfs file and created it again with HA name as location.

```
show create table1 
LOCATION ' hdfs://HA-NAME/data/.... '
```

and it work